# Tie PHP Search with Form Options Selection

Tags: php, sql, ajax, forms, pdo

How can I integrate search results from as the example picture shows?  Right now I have :

```
if(isset($_POST['q'])) {

$q = $_POST['q'];

$select = $db->query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE FName LIKE '%$q%' OR 

LName LIKE '%$q%' ORDER BY ID DESC");

//Search Form Box
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="q" /> <input type="submit" name="search" />
</form>
```

My desired end result is being able to type in a form search field, after the first 3 characters are typed, have the form be selectable and populate from my "items" database table, and be selectable.  The I want to be able to
dynamically add extra form fields(so the user can add items to an invoice).
[image: Example]

Autocomplete code :

```
'$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });'
```

I cannot see how autocomplete would work, with the limited tags code.

Comment: Using something like [autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) will do what you want.

Comment: @Jay_Blanchard it will not, autocomplete will work with only a limited amount of items, I want to tie in a database of possibly 5000+ items

Comment: Autocomplete works perfectly fine with huge databases.

Comment: @Styphon See added code above(autocomplete)

Comment: Please don't dump code in comments. Edit your original post to add any new information.

Comment: The number of items doesn't matter to autocomplete. Once you exceed a certain number it becomes a bad UX though.

Comment: you can use autocomplete with ajax, or load the array with ajax dynamically. There are also plugins like [this](https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/) which can help

Comment: @Jay_Blanchard That is why I wanted to only call the database after the first three(editable) characters are typed, to limit the results

Comment: @insanityCode are there any tutorials online that show how to do this?  From what I surmise, I will have to call the data with ajax, convert it for use for the plugin, then convert it back to be updated by ajax into the form element itself... A little deep for someone new to php :)

Comment: @Steven there's only one way to learn, jump in and get your feet wet. You may struggle with it, but at least try to write the code.

Comment: @Styphon I totally agree, I have learned a great deal about sql and php here lately, just a little wary on trying on jquery and ajax(I still have much more to learn about the prior) :)  This is a great community to be a part of though with the problems that stump especially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want, checkout this Step by Step example :

[How to Create a jquery-ui Autocomplete Step by Step](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/jquery-ui-autocomplete-step-by-step)

It uses `jquery`, `ajax`, `php` and `mysql`.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a good starting point.  I will start here, and try to modify as needed

Comment: @Steven You're welcome! if my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer, tks!